# Is it possible to hyperlink comments in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ Idea for Android devleopment. Is there any way in which I can hyperlink two comments in the IDE. For example

**File**  *a.java*

```
import a;

/**
* This class does something and something
* and does implements interface b, 
* (i want a hyperlink here, if pressed opens file b.java in IDE and cursor is at comments        
*  before method n)
*/

public class a {
  //do something
}
```

**File**  *b.java*

```
import k;

public interface b {

   public j;
   public m;
   /**
    * This will be used when this and this will happen.
   */  
   public n;
}
```

Comment: Why? If a class implements an interface, just go to the interface definition via ctrl-b/cmd-b when you're on the interface implementation declaration. You can always try using normal javadoc links or sees, that will link in the rendered javadocs, not sure about in the ide (where you don't need it).

Comment: @DaveNewton Why? Is not the answer. You should say Yes, this is possible and this is how you do it or No, this is not possible.

Comment: Correct, it's not the answer, hence I didn't answer. That said, knowing your purpose, the "why" behind the question, actually matters. So instead of attacking, consider that someone might have a purpose for asking, and just answer. Geez. Good luck, I'd consider a different approach.

Comment: @DaveNewton It is just for the ease of navigation, just focusing on the what matters. For some people like me it can be very useful during bug tracking. Similar to "share" button at every question and answer on SO.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the point of doing it from the Javadocs if you're already in the IDE; devs should be accustomed to using the code artifact navigation instradqof relying on the docs, which are lies waiting to happen.

Comment: @DaveNewton May you are true but people are really different from each other and for me I fell a hyperlink based navigation in IDE will be really helpful for me.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think now I understood what you was trying to say. Every method in Intellj idea is sort of hyperlink, you just need to press CTRL and click on it, so there is not need for what I was looking but I never knew CTRL+click in IntelliJ. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use Javadocs' `@see` tag - examples [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#see).

It should be sufficient to do something like that:

```
/**
* Bla bla bla
* @see b#n
*/
public class a
```

Comment: That will only create the link in Javadoc I am trying to find is it possible to connect two files in IDE.

Comment: @codingcrow, Try it, you will be able to hold `CTRL` and click to navigate, as with other links. `CTRL+B` works as well.

Comment: Just a note -- the see annotation must exist on its own separate line for clickthrough to work correctly. If you want to link in the same line, use {@link Class#method} as per madMuffin's answer

Comment: works.. but has to be a class/method.. so that sucks for any javascript dev or other methods exports etc.

Answer (score 19):

Current IntelliJ versions support the @link notation, just like Eclipse.

To link to another class/method, just use this pattern:

```
/**
 * {@link Class#method}
 */
public void myMethod() {
}
```

you can also spare the method, or add a list of argument types to the method (in parenthesis), useful if a method is implemented with different parameters and you want to link to a specific one.

Comment: this is not working in inline type of comments (`// comment ... `)

Comment: maybe we tell Google. Links in comments not supported is annoing

Comment: This is not working for me for any reference(other class, function, current class, function, interface, comment , etc) interestingly when i start writin `@` , i see a list of other annotations like `@see`, `@throws` etc, but not @link :/

Comment: @anshsachdeva I just confirmed it with my current IntelliJ 2020.2 and it still works for me. Are you sure you are using the identical syntax as in my example (e.g. long comments, and the curly braces around the link annotation?

Comment: @madmuffin thankyou for the quick response. I was actually trying to write documentation for a kotlin file in Android Studio. Both those words are like siblings of java and Intellij, so I thought this would work. But instead in kotlin , we can make links using  `[Classname/functionName/variable]` syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can use just square brackets for that in the format: `[class.method]`. For your example it will be looked like this:

```
/**
* This class does something and something
* and does implements interface [b.n]
*/
```