# Is it possible to reference a file in comments in IntelliJ Idea platform based IDEs?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, javadoc

I'm using Android Studio for programming Android with Java. As all of us know this IDE is based on IntelliJ Platform. So, Is this possible:

```
// please take a look at ir.domain.project.MyClass.java
```

@Vic in [Is it possible to hyperlink comments in IntelliJ Idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778645/is-it-possible-to-hyperlink-comments-in-intellij-idea) has suggested to use @see javadoc tag but I it is useful when you are generating documentation from code.

What I'm looking for is an IDE based solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I want to be able to click on <ir.domain.project.MyClass.java> and directly go to the mentioned file.

Comment: I sure hope you don't have a file named `ir.domain.project.MyClass.java`. It should be a file named `MyClass.java` in folder `ir/domain/project`. And yes, you can use the javadoc `{@link ir.domain.project.MyClass}` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a link (control-click in windows, command-click in Mac) like below:

```
/**
* please take a look at {@link ir.domain.project.MyClass}
*/
```

You can also link to a specific method:

```
/**
* please take a look at {@link ir.domain.project.MyClass#myMethod(int)}
*/
```

IntelliJ provides auto completion as you type - you can utilize that to ensure the link is correct.